# Adding a value to an array in a separate .js file

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

Having searched and tried a few different methods, I'm not having success, so looking for help on what I'm doing wrong.

I have a page index.html that has the following in the head section:

`<script src="/assets/config.js"></script>`

And this at the end of the body section:

`<script src="/assets/app.js"></script>`

In app.js I have the following:

```
let newName = inputName; // <-- this comes from an html text box

if (configs && configs.name) {
    console.log(" - - adding new name: " + newName);
    try {
        configs.name.push(newName);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error: " + err.name + " - " + err.message);
    }
}
```

In config.js I have the following:

```
var configs = {
    name: ["adam","joe","jerry"]
}
```

When i run the code, it seems like it should work.  I get no errors in the console, but the new value is not added to the array.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you `console.log(configs.name)` right after pushin the `newName`?

Comment: array.prototype.push doesn't throw exceptions

Comment: is this line getting logged on the console? `console.log(" - - adding new name: " + newName);`

Comment: @Onheiron It shows Undefined.  (at)samuellawrentz - yes, it shows the name it should be adding.   (at)Lawrence Cherone - it says 'undefined is not an object.'

Comment: @Onheiron I was wrong - mistyped it.  It shows the new name at the end of the array.  But int he file, it's not updated.

Comment: "in the file"...
The program execution is not going to override the content of `config.js` the file itself will always have `name: ["adam","joe","jerry"]` in it. If you want to update the contents of the `config.js` file you need a different approach.